# How do I revise Django's authentication module?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm relatively new to Django, and am trying to make some changes to Django's core authentication module. I added some new code that authenticates a user based on their email address to the `authenticate` method of the `ModelBackend` class in `django.contrib.auth.backends.py`, however this new code doesn't seem to have any effect, even when I added the below to my settings.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

In fact I deleted the entire `authenticate` method and was still able to log into my Django application just fine. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here, and what the best way is to revise Django's core authentication system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to import the `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` backend into a module, subclass it, overriding `authenticate` in the process, and then point `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` at your subclass. See the section on [writing your own authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) in the manual. In fact, you should read the whole page.

Don't alter anything in `django.contrib` directly.  It will get blown away with the next upgrade.  Subclass it or look for ways to hook into it.

I'm not surprised authentication worked when you ripped things out. Django's authentication is an add-on; Django needs to be able to work without it, so the default will be "allow".

Comment: thanks @Mike DeSimone, that makes sense. quick follow up question, what are the pros/cons of this approach vs just writing my own login view?

Comment: The biggest pro is: you don't have to write all that code. Ask yourself if you need to write your own view, or if you just need a different template. You can override the template for the login page and tell Django to use it.